# Quartz Cron Expression for running a job every 5 hours from a given time

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz library for scheduling. I have to schedule a job every 5           (could be variable) hours from a given time.

I tried using the following expression -

**0 0 12/5 1/1 * ? ***

I checked the output of future runs at [Cronmaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/).

Schedule Start Time -> Tuesday, June 21, 2017 10:30 AM

Future runs -

1. Wednesday, June 21, 2017 12:00 PM
2. Wednesday, June 21, 2017 5:00 PM
3. Wednesday, June 21, 2017 10:00 PM
4. Thursday, June 22, 2017 12:00 PM

The expression does what it is asked but I was hoping that the 4th run would be 5 hours in addition to the 3rd run i.e something along these lines -

1. Wednesday, June 21, 2017 12:00 PM
2. Wednesday, June 21, 2017 5:00 PM
3. Wednesday, June 21, 2017 10:00 PM
4. Thursday, June 22, 2017 3:00 AM

The 4th run goes to next day's 12:00 PM trigger. I want it to be added to the last run's time.
Is there any way via which this can be achieved via the cron-expression?

Comment: The correct expression is `0 0 0/5 1/1 * ? *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CronSchedule` is not the best suited one for what you want to do.

Use **`SimpleSchedule`** instead:

```
trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("yourJobName", "yourJobGroup")
    .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
        .withIntervalInHours(5) // every 5 hours
        .repeatForever()) // keep going in intervals of 5h
    .startAt(dateOf(12, 0, 0)) // start at 12:00 PM
    .build();
```

You can find more examples in the [official documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05.html).